# Using Sum(Cast(Replace syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a simple query in order to change some of our stage data. I have a varchar $ column (unfortunately) that needs to be summed. My issue is that because of commas, I cannot change the datatype.
So, I can use `REPLACE(AMT,',','')` to remove the commas but It still wont let me cast it as a decimal and I get

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I am trying the following below with no luck. Any ideas? Can this be done or am I using the wrong syntax here?

`Select SUM(Cast(REPLACE(Amt,',','') as Decimal (18,2)) )`

Comment: could you please post the value in `amt` it fails to convert?

Comment: You probably have some oddity in your "Amt" column that you're not accounting for (i.e. something that isn't just numbers and commas). Maybe try finding it (e.g. with `SELECT Amt... WHERE ISNUMERIC(Amt) = 0` or using PATINDEX or something).

Comment: @Geo, you may have some spaces on your AMT. Try 
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Amt)),',','') as DECIMAL(18,2)))

Comment: Try `Cast( Cast( Amt as Money ) as Decimal(18,2) )`. The cast to money is rather more forgiving.

Comment: Some of my Amt values are of the following:

-37,567.57

-163,235.2

-52,209.43

126,563.73

-9,660.87

-18,112.36

-7,589.3

So I am using `REPLACE` to get rid of the commas but I am not sure what else could be causing the failure.

Comment: @JKarthik your suggestion worked. I would mark this answer as complete thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with @HABO suggestion. I used `Cast(Ltrim(rtrim(table.AMT)) as Money)` for all instances of the `varchar` amount. This removed white space and removed the commas from the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work... including an example.

Edit: if you are on SQL Server 2012+, you may be able to shorten your task by using [Try_Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

```
DECLARE @SomeTable AS TABLE (Amt Varchar(100));
INSERT INTO @Sometable (Amt) VALUES ('abc123,456.01'),('  123,456.78 '),(Null),('asdad'),('');

With NumericsOnly AS 
  (
    SELECT
      REPLACE(Left(SubString(Amt, PatIndex('%[0-9.-,]%', Amt), 8000), PatIndex('%[^0-9.,-]%', SubString(Amt, PatIndex('%[0-9.,-]%', Amt), 8000) + 'X')-1),',','') AS CleanAmt
    FROM
      @SomeTable
  )

  SELECT
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), CleanAmt)) AS TotalAmt
  FROM
    NumericsOnly
  WHERE
    IsNumeric(CleanAmt)=1
```

General methodology is taken from [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use money as a data type as it is notorious for rounding error.

The error is due to SQL order of operations within your SUM(CAST(REPLACE... operation. This issue can be resolved by summing the column AFTER it's been staged to be summed via a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(Field),... 
FROM ( SELECT 
       Cast(REPLACE(Amt,',','') as NUMERIC) as 'Field' 
       ,...
     ) [Q]
```

If the table you're summing is administered by a BI Team, get them to stage the data there. Happy Data Happy life.